# Control screen orientation in my special case

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

I would like to launch **Google Play** app programatically, I know there are **2** ways to do it:

**The 1st way:**

```
final String appName = ...;
try {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id="+appName)));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+appName)));
}
```

The above code launch the Google Play & open the page of a specific app in the store.

**The 2nd way:**

```
Context context = getContext();
Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(GOOGLE_PLAY_PACKAGE_NAME);
if(intent!=null){               
    context.startActivity(intent);  
}
```

The above way simply launch the Google Play app.

Since I don't care which page of Google Play is shown as long as it is launched, so either way is fine for me. **Here comes my key question:**

Besides launch Google Play, I would also like to set the **orientation** (Portrait or Landscape) **programatically** to control the display mode when Google Play is launched. How can I achieve this with above options in hands?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is **not possible.**
Only a developer from a app can set the screen orientation programatically or if he give a option to set the orientation with a intent.

So it is possible to set the screenorientation from an activity with a intent. The following example illustrates a possible solution.

*Yourcode*

```
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;

public class YourClass extends Activity {

private void yourMethodToStartAnNewActivity() {
    Intent intent = null;   
    try {
        Intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id="+appName)));
        intent.putExtra("screenOrientation", ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        startActivity(intent);
    } 
    catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play is not installed on your device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }       
}
}
```

*Activity to start*

```
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;

public class ActivtyToStart extends Activity {

private final static int NO_SCREENORIENTATION_SET = 999;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int screenOrientation = extras.getInt("screenOrientation", NO_SCREENORIENTATION_SET);

    switch (screenOrientation) {
    case ActivtyToStart.NO_SCREENORIENTATION_SET:
        break;
    case ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        break;
    case ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);  
        break;
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activitytoStart);
}
```

Good luck!